# BorderLayout изменить размеры областей

Tags: java, swing

Как сделать, чтобы в BorderLayout TOP не заполнял весь фрейм, а Left & Right заполняли?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

компоненту "А" с borderlayout (с "элементами" top, center, bottom) нужно положить в CENTER другого контейнера "B" с borderlayout (с элементами left, right, center aka "А" )

```
public class TestFrame1 extends JFrame
{
    public TestFrame1 ()
    {
        setSize ( 400, 400 ) ;
        setLayout ( new BorderLayout () ) ;
        setDefaultCloseOperation ( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE ) ;

        // left
        final JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel () ;
        leftPanel.setBackground ( Color.BLUE ) ;
        add ( leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST ) ;

        // right 
        final JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel () ;
        rightPanel.setBackground ( Color.YELLOW ) ;
        add ( rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST ) ;

        // center
        final JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel ( new BorderLayout () ) ;

        // center top
        final JPanel centerTop = new JPanel () ;
        centerTop.setBackground ( Color.RED ) ;
        centerPanel.add ( centerTop, BorderLayout.NORTH ) ;

        // center bottom
        final JPanel centerBottom = new JPanel () ;
        centerBottom.setBackground ( Color.GREEN ) ;
        centerPanel.add ( centerBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH ) ;

        add ( centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER ) ;
    }

    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        new TestFrame1 ().setVisible ( true ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BorderLayout - это layout в контейнере, условного расположение элемента, если тебе надо внутри расположить что-то еще, вложи в него другой, подходящий контейнер и размещай элементы в нем

Comment: Я умею размещать. Фишка в том шо этот лайтаут растягивается. Надо просто шоб Left перекрывал Тор, а не наоборот!

Comment: используй как главный FlowLayout, первым в него помести отдельный леяут или фрейм, вторым BorderLayout( в нем, если надо, не используй, левый и правый край), ну и 3м - еще одни фрейм, получится как у тебя на рисунке